# Flyway migration throwing Validation error

Tags: flyway

While running migration through `flyway` command line in `Jenkins` I am getting below error:

> ERROR: Unexpected error org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException:
>   Validate failed: Detected applied migration not resolved locally:
>   12.0.4

Currently I am trying to run 20.0.1 which is lagtest version and earlier versions are not present in the files location.
I observed by the info that there are applied higher versions than 12.0.4(which is base version) on DB which are in missing state.

Can anyone help me why this error is occurring and how to resolve this?

Comment: you need to provide more information such as running though command line mode or though api. And whether the migration files location contains this 12.0.4 migration or not.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question. I have updated more details in my question and also mentioned here.
I ran this using command line mode and older migration files were not present in the files path. 12.0.4 is the baseline version here.

Comment: Hi, with flyway migration you need the entire set of migration files already run to be present in the files location along with the migrations to be run. This is because flyway will validate if any applied migration has had changed - checksum validations.

Comment: If you do not want the earlier migrations then, you need to backup the schema_migration table and then re-do a baseline. HTH

Comment: Thanks for the solution and information. I will try baselining.

Comment: I could not find schema_migration table in my DB. Is there any way to skip validation part and apply/execute newer version using config parameters in community edition.

Comment: See if https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate#ignoreMissingMigrations option will help you.

Comment: I found validateOnMigrate config parameter. Making it false at command line worked perfect. Thanks Sudhir.